# How may I replace word and digit combination with blank?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, digits

How to replace

url : `http://www.abc.com&query_id=123&query_id1=12`

to : `http://www.abc.com&query_id1=12`

How to replace any query_id with blank in javascript ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var url = "http://www.abc.com&query_id=123&query_id1=12";
    url = url.replace(/(\?|&)query_id=[^&]*/g, "");

console.log(url); /* returns http://www.abc.com&query_id1=12 */
```

anyway note that you should replace the first occurence of `&` with a `?`

`http://www.abc.com&query_id=123&query_id1=12`

should be written as

`http://www.abc.com?query_id=123&query_id1=12`